# Performing Calculations Across Columns More Efficiently (R Studio)

Tags: r, calculation

I'm using R 4.1.0

Let's say I have a data frame called my_df and it looks like this:

| ID | x |
| --- | --- |
| A | 24 |
| B | 108 |
| C | 76 |

and I want to calculate each value of column x as such:

```
(x/180) * 100
```

and place the result in a new column so it will look like this:

| ID | x | y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 24 | 13.33 |
| B | 108 | 60 |
| C | 76 | 42.22 |

What I have tried is a for loop:

```
for (i in 1: length(my_df) {
   my_df$y[i] <- (my_df$x[i]/180) * 100
}
```

The above code works. However, the actual data frame I'm working with is over a million rows long. When I run that for loop for my data frame, it takes a really long time to execute.

So, my question is: is there a way to execute the above in a more efficient way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://www.noamross.net/archives/2014-04-16-vectorization-in-r-why/

Comment: Excuse me for my curiosity, but how did you end up using R but not knowing that operations are vectorized?

Comment: Speaking for myself, I had never heard of the concept of "vectorized" operations when I started to use R, even though it kept coming up in descriptions of the R language. It was not a part of my experience with other programming languages, so explanations like in the post above helped me understand why it made so much of a difference to restructure my code to take advantage of vectorization.

Comment: As a general rule of thumb in R try thinking in lists as opposed to loops. R data structures are defined in terms of lists.  R *uses* the information embodied in the various list structures (data frames, tibbles, matrices, etc., etc.) to do all the looping (recursion too, btw in dataframes and other list structures) under the hood without the coder having to worry about silly little things like indeces. ...Basically, if you are an R beginner and you are asking what kind of loop to code, you are simply stating you aren't thinking in R yet and the best advice to give--as Jon did--is to not loop.

Comment: @dash2 R is something that I'm learning on my own as I go. I had used C# and C++ and that's how I learned about loops, but I had never worked with data frames. So, I was basically trying to implement what I'm familiar with.

Comment: @cmartini86 no worries and good luck. I'd recommend Hadley Wickham's books (available online) as places to start.

Answer (score 1):

We don't need a loop as arithmetic operations are vectorized (should be much faster than looping)

```
my_df$y <- 100 *(my_df$x/180)
```